# Assigning a dynamic variable in Javascript in a template for URLs

Tags: javascript, django, django-urls

I am working on trying to assign a dynamic variable in Javascript within my template for URLs. This is to pass the data back to the page. At the moment this is hard coded. I'm stuck trying to figure out best way to fix this. Here is my code:

**JS**

```
function MyModule.init() {
var myXHR = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    seconds = (new Date()).getTime();

// Load my data
myXHR.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    var preXHR = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        data;

    if (myXHR.readyState === 4) {
        data = JSON.parse(myXHR.responseText);

        timestamp = data['timestamp'];
        myData = data['my'];

        // Load rep data
        preXHR.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if (preXHR.readyState === 4) {
                repData = JSON.parse(preXHR.responseText)['reps'];

                organizeData();
                showMYTable();
            }
        });

        // This hardcoded path is what I am trying to change, as it is bad
        preXHR.open('GET', '/catalog/1/my-reps?t=' + seconds); 

        preXHR.send();
    }
});

// This hardcoded path is what I am trying to change, as it is bad
myXHR.open('GET', '/catalog/1/my-data?t=' + seconds);

myXHR.send();
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        MyModule.init('{% url catalog.data %}');
    });
</script>
```

**URL**

```
url(r'^(?P<company>.+)/(?P<name>.+)', 'data', name='catalog.data')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be already passing the URL into the `MyModule.init()` function, but you're not doing anything with it there. Just reference it as a variable:

```
function MyModule.init(url) {
    ...

    myXHR.open('GET', url + '?t=' + seconds);
```

Comment: I got this working but seems that setting up my function this way is giving me syntax errors...`SPPModule not defined error` What is a better way to set up this function?